# Is it possible to create class objects based on input from the user?

Tags: java, object, mapping

I have a class for creating basic grocery store items (class storeItems).  I want to allow the user to make their own grocery store item by creating a new class object based on parameters that I receive from the user; i.e: "What is the name?" "What is the price?" "How much in stock?" etc. I also do not want to define the number of objects that can be created, so that it can be expanded as needed by the user.

Everything is properly structured, other than the object variable names themselves.

How would I go about creating these objects? Most of my Googling has suggested to use maps, but I can't for the life of me figure out how I would structure this.

This is essentially what I am trying to do:

```
public static Map<String,storeItems> storeItemMapper = new HashMap<String,storeItems>();

public static void itemBuilder(String mapObjName, String itemName, double price, int initialQuantity) {
    storeItems object[i] = new storeItems(itemName, price, initialQuantity);

    storeItemMapper.put(mapObjName, object[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What isn't works as you planned? Btw, Class names should be in Camel Case standard, i.e, StoreItems instead of storeItems.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly indexing the variable declaration:

```
storeItems object[i] = new storeItems(itemName, price, initialQuantity);
```

Try:

```
storeItems object = new storeItems(itemName, price, initialQuantity);
```

Without the index [i]. And as I said in the commentary, you should to use the CamelCase standard to name classes:

```
StoreItems object = new StoreItems(itemName, price, initialQuantity);
```

Comment: I know that object[i] does not work, I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to name an object just based on user input. This was the best way to explain what I'm trying to do. To give an example: I would ask for input, and then i = reader.nextLine();

Comment: What you mean by "name an object"? Set an attribute value of the object or making a mapping ("name" -> object) in order to retrieve the object later based in this name? In the last case, the Map interface and its implementations (HashMap, Hashtable, TreeMap, ...) can provide an ephemeral mechanism (in memory). If you need something persistent you should to use a serialized form, as a file based persistence, or a save the object into a database relational or non relational.

Comment: I'm trying to let the user give the input for the object variable name.

Comment: I see. The name of the variable must be statically defined at compile time, not in runtime. If you want to store the object someway you can assign a name at runtime, use a Map data structure.